# Payara 4.1 autodeploy WAR deploy error NullPointerException NCLS-CORE-00069 AS-WEB-CORE-00108

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, web-deployment, payara

after some code changes I observe a very odd exception from the payara server. The problem with it, I cannot pinpoint down what it is complaining about. Basically I don't know even what is wrong.

**Any ideas what could be wrong are much appreciated.**

Exceptions in the log during startup:

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-07-14T11:31:34.430+0000","Level":"WARNING","Version":"Payara 4.1","LoggerName":"javax.enterprise.system.core","ThreadID":"58","ThreadName":"AutoDeployer","TimeMillis":"1531567894430","LevelValue":"900","MessageID":"NCLS-CORE-00069","LogMessage":{"Exception":"Exception while dispatching an event","StackTrace":"org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationException
    at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:505)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:536)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at org.glassfish
.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:484)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
"}}
```

Followed by -- twice:

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-07-14T11:31:34.998+0000","Level":"SEVERE","Version":"Payara 4.1","LoggerName":"javax.enterprise.web.core","ThreadID":"58","ThreadName":"AutoDeployer","TimeMillis":"1531567894998","LevelValue":"1000","MessageID":"AS-WEB-CORE-00108","LogMessage":{"Exception":"ContainerBase.addChild: start: ","StackTrace":"org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5523)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:509)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:536)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.e
xecute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:484)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2884)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:2080)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:239)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5520)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:3005)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:5043)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1732)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2882)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:2102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:3003)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createManagedObject(JCDIServiceImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:476)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:429)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:337)
    ... 47 more
"}}
```

This warning comes later a couple of times

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-07-14T11:31:35.079+0000","Level":"WARNING","Version":"Payara 4.1","LoggerName":"javax.enterprise.web","ThreadID":"58","ThreadName":"AutoDeployer","TimeMillis":"1531567895079","LevelValue":"900","LogMessage":{"Exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener","StackTrace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:509)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:536)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at j
ava.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:484)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
"}}
```

These exceptions are now repeated multiple times followed by the container has not yet started exception and in the end the good old "Autodeploy failed"

**Locally it deploys fine**, only on the server (OpenShift Linux Pod) it fails. 
This are the only warnings I get on a local successful deploy (app runs):

```
WARNUNG:   Could not load service class fish.payara.appserver.roles.api.extension.RolesCDIExtension
WARNUNG:   Could not load service class fish.payara.appserver.roles.api.extension.RolesCDIExtension
WARNUNG:   Could not load service class fish.payara.appserver.roles.api.extension.RolesCDIExtension
Information:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARNUNG:   The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Parameter interceptedBean of type javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean from private javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean org.glassfish.soteria.cdi.LoginToContinueInterceptor.interceptedBean is not resolvable to a concrete type.

WARNUNG:   The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Parameter interceptedBean of type javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean from private javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean org.glassfish.soteria.cdi.RememberMeInterceptor.interceptedBean is not resolvable to a concrete type.

WARNUNG:   Class class [Ljava.lang.String; has null package
INFORMATION:   Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01 for context ''
INFORMATION:   Mojarra 2.2.14 (-SNAPSHOT 20170628-1326 unable to get svn info) für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.
WARN:   WELD-000718: No EEModuleDescriptor defined for bean archive with ID: XXXXXXXXX_war.war. @Initialized and @Destroyed events for ApplicationScoped may be fired twice.
```

What have I tried:

- Reverted any version updates of any libs
- removed any Startup EJBs -- which in the end showed the above error
- Verified the configuration

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The exception is most probably a deployment error caused by your application or configuration. Payara Server has a bug that it doesn't log the original exception but throws only a subsequent exception, so you can't see what's wrong in your application from the log messages.

The issue with logging the original message is described in https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2332. It's fixed in Payara 5.182 and users also reported that the new weld version in 5.182 removed their deployment error.

You may try upgrading to Payara 5.182. If that's not possible, you may find out what's causing the deployment problem by debugging your the server, putting an exception breakpoint on `DeploymentException` and check the message of the exception.

Comment: Thanks of the link -- I will try this out with the 4.1.2.182.1 -- I couldn't find this version till now to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I could pin it down to the Payara version (docker image). It seems like that where is a bigger difference between:

```
sh-4.2$ ./asadmin version
Version = Payara Server  4.1.2.181 #badassfish (build 220)
Command version executed successfully.
```

Which works fine and:

```
sh-4.2$ ./asadmin version
Version = Payara Server  4.1.2.182.1 #badassfish (build 308)
Command version executed successfully.
```

Which causes the error above. I haven't looked into the details till now -- and just reverted the version of the Payara to 4.1.2.181 again.

Disclaimer: As it is a docker image it is possible, that the payara was modified and it has nothing todo with the payara itself. I haven't verified that, as mentioned above.

Comment: I see you're using version 4.1.2.182.1 which is a patch version and not publicly available. Is it possible that your company has a support contract for Payara? You'd probably get help also via private support channels.

Comment: True -- on the developer machines we use the public versions. On the company systems we have this Version by default -- to which we don't have access. I am already pretty sure it is that patched version which is somehow buggy.

Comment: You should have access to the private version also for development. You should contact a responsible person in your company or contact Payara support at support@payara.fish. You won't get answers for a private version of Payara on public forums like this.